# Microsoft EWS Get Available Conference Room

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, calendar, exchangewebservices

I am developing an ASP.NET web app using Microsoft Exchange Web Services (managed API). My goal is to provide a list of conference room addresses as input, and get back busy/free info from the Exchange server using `GetUserAvailability` so that I can suggest an open conference room to the user for a given meeting time. I have working code, but when I try to limit the `DetailedSuggestionsWindow` to the meeting duration, I get an error:

> The time duration specified for `FreeBusyViewOptions.TimeWindow` is invalid.

I know I can expand the time window - but then I'm getting more data back than I need. Can anyone provide a way to find a suggested conference room for a certain time (typically 30 mins - 2 hrs)?

Comment: What time window are you trying to use ? Why is too much data a problem for you ? if you are getting the correct data just filter out what you don't need at the client. I would suggest you include the code your try in your question as that will help people trying to answer.

Comment: @GlenScales because EWS seems to be choosing optimal meeting windows where the maximum number of attendees are available, not providing free/busy info for an exact timeframe. So if I know I want a meeting from 2-3, and I supply a 24 hour window, I'm not guaranteed to get back for the timeslot I care about if it's not one of the best results. I don't really care what percentage of attendees are available, just that at least one attendee (Conf. room) is available. I tried your suggestion, and did post-filtering to see if it returned the expected result and it did not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between a DateTime object I create and DateTime.Now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750937/difference-between-a-datetime-object-i-create-and-datetime-now)

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the below link:

```
// Create a collection of attendees. 
List<AttendeeInfo> attendees = new List<AttendeeInfo>(); 

attendees.Add(new AttendeeInfo() 
{ 
    SmtpAddress = "mack@contoso.com", 
    AttendeeType = MeetingAttendeeType.Organizer 
}); 

attendees.Add(new AttendeeInfo() 
{ 
    SmtpAddress = "sadie@contoso.com", 
    AttendeeType = MeetingAttendeeType.Required 
}); 

// Specify options to request free/busy information and suggested meeting times.
AvailabilityOptions availabilityOptions = new AvailabilityOptions(); 
availabilityOptions.GoodSuggestionThreshold = 49; 
availabilityOptions.MaximumNonWorkHoursSuggestionsPerDay = 0;
availabilityOptions.MaximumSuggestionsPerDay = 2;
// Note that 60 minutes is the default value for MeetingDuration, but setting it explicitly for demonstration purposes.
availabilityOptions.MeetingDuration = 60; 
availabilityOptions.MinimumSuggestionQuality = SuggestionQuality.Good; 
availabilityOptions.DetailedSuggestionsWindow = new TimeWindow(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), DateTime.Now.AddDays(2));
availabilityOptions.RequestedFreeBusyView = FreeBusyViewType.FreeBusy;

// Return free/busy information and a set of suggested meeting times. 
// This method results in a GetUserAvailabilityRequest call to EWS.
GetUserAvailabilityResults results = service.GetUserAvailability(attendees, 
                                                                 availabilityOptions.DetailedSuggestionsWindow, 
                                                                 AvailabilityData.FreeBusyAndSuggestions, 
                                                                 availabilityOptions);
```

For more information, please refer to this link:

[Get appointments from coworker via EWS only with “Free / Busy time, subject, location” permission level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43759529/get-appointments-from-coworker-via-ews-only-with-free-busy-time-subject-loc)

Comment: This is the code I'm using. When I decrease the `DetailedSuggestionTimeWindow`, to a typical meeting duration, I get the error described.

Comment: According to my search, this actually appears to be an issue in the GetUserAvailability method as opposed to any DateTime manipulation. For more information, please refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750937/difference-between-a-datetime-object-i-create-and-datetime-now

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping there was a better way to get only the info desired, but it doesn't look like there is. I will flag my question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.getuseravailability

> method supports only time periods that are a minimum of 24 hours long
>   and that begin and end at 12:00a.m. To restrict the results of the
>   method to a shorter time period, you must filter the results on the
>   client.

So, you can't pass the time window you want. Try removing the attendees and querying for availability of only rooms to get a more complete result set back.